# Writing to an external SD card from native code on Android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-ndk, storage-access-framework

Users of my app complain that the app can't write to an external SD card. Upon researching the issue, I've come to a conclusion that the app must use the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) in order to write to an external SD card. But what if I need to be able to write files from native code? Is there any way to request this permission? Is there a way to request a specific folder to be writable from my app?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760025/android-write-files-to-usb-via-otg-cable/28760222#28760222

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is claimed in `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. List item

`Activity.getExternalFilesDirs()` to get the dir

Comment: That's the problem: I want to write to an arbitrary directory, not just to the one returned by `getExternalFilesDirs`.

Comment: May I ask why you need it? As far as I can tell, the mounting dir for external storage is very device specific.

Comment: Yes, it is device specific. But my understanding is that `getExternalFilesDirs` doesn't just return the external storage's root (its mounting point). It returns a specific folder within that storage, the only folder I'm allowed to write to. Did I get that wrong?