# What permission do I need to write to a usb pen drive on Android?

Tags: android, permissions, storage, usb-drive

In my app, I need to write a file on an USB pen drive. On Samsung Tab 4, I have no problem at all, both in reading and in writing. My apps works great.

On Asus Zenpad 10, something is different...
I have no problem in reading from usb pen drive.
On the contrary, I have access denied when writing, i.e getting exception in the code:

```
 try {
    fOut = new FileOutputStream("/storage/USBdisk/prova.bin");
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    return;
 }
```

In my androidManifest, the permissions are defined as:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Usually *USB pendrive will know as SD card*,
But the permission in Androidmanifest.xml need to declare different permission, *USB external storage need media enable* permission like below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
```

Please read [android official document](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

EX:

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
    "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(device != null){
                      //call method to set up device communication
                   }
                } 
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

check [Storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/) and [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760025/android-write-files-to-usb-via-otg-cable)

Comment: Unfortunely, permission WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE is only granted to system apps...
On samsung Tab 4, I'm able to write on USB disk. On asus zenpad10, I'm not.
It could be system on asus treat USB pendisk like external SD card and deny access for third party apps.

Answer (score 0):

**After researching in another sources i found this.. it may help you!**

As a serial converter is a USB device, the android tablet has to act as a USB host. This feature is available since Android 3.1. The API documentation is available on the android developer page and includes code examples.

To actually communicate with the converter you will have to find out a bit more about it's internals: There are many different devices on the market, some using USB HID, others are using USB CDC device class or do not even comply to any class. The linux lsusb command might be helpful to get the device/interface descriptors.

On a typical CDC device you will have to interact with two bulk endpoints and probably use some interface related requests to setup the baudrate, etc. See the Communication Device Class specification on USB implementers forum.

If your device has only one IN and one OUT bulk endpoint (beside the control endpoint) you might try to use the UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer() method on the OUT endpoint to write some bytes to the serial line. There is a good chance this will just work, however for a clean implementation you should stick to the class specification.